# How to use @Contract annotation

Tags: android, annotations

I am trying to learn how to develop start-up apps fastly by using libraries and annotations. I have already experinced @NonNull, @Nullable ones.

While reading javadocs i noticed there is a @Contract annotation which has usage @Contract("null->fail") that makes compilation error if null passed.

Thats really cool feature but i cant use it because there is no annotation class in support.annotations package.

How can i get this feature? Or which library to import?

Thanks.

Comment: I researched and found that its only available in intellij. How can i get this for Android Studio?

Comment: Did you ever find an answer for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add jetbrains' `annotations jar` to your classpath. You can find it in [maven central](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Corg.jetbrains%7Cannotations%7C13.0%7Cjar) or locally, in `<IntelliJ IDEA Home>/lib/annotations.jar`

[image]

Comment: hey Emre, here: http://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2013/10/better-control-flow-analysis-with-contract-annotations-and-intellij-idea-13/ you can find some details about @Contract + IntelliJ Idea